# How to remove cell background color when moving item in list in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to make a reorderable list with custom cells in SwiftUI.
Everything works fine but when I move an item in the list with the onMove function a white background is added to the moving item like shown in the picture. Is it possible to remove this white background?

[image: Moving item with white background]

This is my current code:

```
struct TrainingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var plans: Plans
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(plans.plans) { plan in
                    Text(plan.name)
                        .listRowBackground(Rectangle()
                            .background(.clear)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        )
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }

            .searchable(text: $search)
            .navigationTitle("Test")
        }
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        plans.plans.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
     }
}
```

Comment: Figure it out..?